# Using DataSet to ReadXML File With Subnodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that I would like to load into a DataSet.

The XML file is from a logging system that I have no control over; which is creating a few challenges that I need help with in parsing...

The XML file looks something like this:

```
<LogEntry>
<DateTime></DateTime>
<AppId></AppId>
<Description>
   <EncryptedData>
      <CipherValue></CipherValue>
   </EncryptedData>
</Description>
<Module></Module>
</LogEntry>
```

Note:
  There is no XML DocType.   Not sure if this is necessary for DataSet?

Typically, there is no root node.  Such as " and " opening and closing tags for the document unless the program is stopped/restarted.   It seems to create the root node on startup, but if files are deleted due to size during runtime, it won't recreate root node.

Problem #1 -
What is the best way to handle the missing root node issue?   Should I open file and look for it before attempting to load via DataSet's ReadXML() function and prepend, if necessary -- and appended?

Problem #2 -
The entries with subnodes do not appear to be loading in the DataSet.  The ReadXML() appears to be skipping this element; since I get an error when trying to access that specific column and it tell me it doesn't exist.   I.E., "Description" above.

Problem #3 -
When I get the "Description" column to load, I need to accdess the "CipherValue" data as it is BASE64 encoded.  I will have to decrypt this information.   I have the info for this.

Accessing the "Description" column so I can decrypt the data is the primary reason I'm going through this excercise.  Note there are really more columns and a few more subnodes... but the same basic idea.

I'm trying to use a DataSet because I think it would make working with the rather large XML file easier?   Maybe there is a better way?

The below code, as an example, works, but again I'm not seeing the subnodes (I commented out the line that returns column doesn't exist):

```
Console.WriteLine("Rows found = {0}", dt.Rows.Count);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", 
    row["DateTime"], 
    row["AppId"],
    //row["Description"],
    row["Module"]
    );
```

I suppose I need an XML schema -- but I'm not sure how to write this (even for the example above) so that I can read the data the way I want.

Any help or direction with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I were you I'd look into XDocument (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) instead of the DataSet since I don't know how you would get that Description element to be correct with a dataset.  If you have the option, you could do a text replace before reading it into xml and just remove the "<Description><EncrytedData>" and "</EncryptedData></Description>" leaving only the one you care about.  The DataSet may take that.

Comment: if you insist on using DataSet then you can do the following
`DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();`
`var dir = @"yourPath+Name of your .xml";`
`dataSet.ReadXml(dir);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataSet class is not meant for general-purpose XML input and output. It is an in-memory representation of a relational database model. It can't represent anything that could not be represented as a relational database.

Your data could be modeled as a `LogEntry` table with `DateTime`, `AppId` and `Module` columns. But what is `Description`? It's not a foreign key to an `EncryptedData` table - there's no **id** on either side!

Comment: Thanks - I think I'm going to create my own data class called LogEntry and loop through the XML and add to LIST of LogEntry... and then finally loop through LIST to display whichever way....